# Debian Router (DIY) Website Timeout Problems

Tags: debian, ssl, tcp, nftables, netfilter

I've been setting up a DIY router using Debian. I'm at a point where it's routing traffic to the internet for my client devices. However I'm having trouble accessing websites.

Some websites load quickly, some take a while and some simply timeout (`ERR_TIMED_OUT`). I have absolutely no idea what's causing these timeouts. My DNS resolutions are working.

I'm using a USB network adapter `enx7cc2c643f225` for the WAN interface with the `pppd` service establishing a connection to my ISP through `ppp0`.

I've captured a pcap of the connection attempts one of the websites which timeout and the connections appears thus:

[image]

It is like this for the other websites I can't access too. I have custom firewall (`nftables`) rules, including those [here](https://blog.samuel.domains/blog/security/nftables-hardening-rules-and-good-practices), but I disabled the security focused rules and still no connection. I've tried `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_sack` but that doesn't seem to have done anything.

My `nftables.conf` can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/iALq4HCL).

What could be causing these issues? Thanks in advance

Comment: use the web browser to determine what is failing to load

Comment: To avoid having us guessing, can you give the actual ruleset you're currently using? `nft list ruleset`

Comment: Are you allow/block icmp? Its may be pdmtu related problem

Comment: I'd concur that it would be worth looking at packet sizes on blocked connections and MTU. Something else _en route_ may be dropping ICMP and preventing MTU negotiation

Comment: I've just tried using `wget` on the site from the router and it accesses it fine. So it must be some forwarding issues? @gapsf I'm not explicitly blocking ICMP I don't think. The only `drop` hits I get when using `nft monitor trace` are seemingly non-related packets. I'll see about getting my `nft` ruleset posted.

Comment: I've just added a rule to `nftables` to the `forward` chain the `mangle` table: `meta l4proto tcp tcp flags & (syn|rst) == syn counter packets 0 bytes 0 tcp option maxseg size set rt mtu` and I now seem to be able to access the websites I couldn't previously

Comment: Still didn't give your actual ruleset, did you? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/715937/edit) your question and add it (`nft list ruleset`).

Comment: Post edited to include my `nftables.conf` file.

Comment: Well: comments suggest Docker is around: 1st bad idea because Docker affects the bridge path (I see there are also bridge rules btw). dropping fragments: bad idea. having multiple rules about tcp flag: useless (Netfilter does it already, more thoroughly). I'm leaving this. Looks a bit too complex for me.

Comment: No worries, thanks anyway. My Docker `daemon.json` includes `iptables: false` so I can use `nftables` to configure the rules myself. The rule I added in the comment earlier does seem to have resolved the trouble in connecting to certain websites, I'll wait a bit more before I try and answer my own question just in case.

Comment: Temporarly cleanup ALL you firewall rules except snat rules, set policy to accept and check is it works.